# How to remove or hide text from existing pdf using itextsharp c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Is there any way to remove or hide field in existing PDF document using iTextSharp library.
Instead of removing I have tried to add white color like

```
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(new Bitmap(130, 20), BaseColor.WHITE);
```

it is showing

> Error CS7069  Reference to type 'Image' claims it is defined in
>   'System.Drawing', but it could not be found

Thanks.

Comment: In the itextsharp.xtra assembly you can find the `PdfCleanUp*` classes which feature redaction.

Comment: @mkl thanks for the help by using PdfCleanUpProcessor I am able to hide the text. I have another question, how to  insert the text in pdf after CleanUp()?

Comment: To add text to an existing PDF you can either use the `ColumnText` class (in simple cases, e.g. a one-liner, the static `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned` methods should suffice) or use the low-level text drawing instructions of `PdfContentByte` directly.